# Nuke own python version, how to install, add or wrap new modules?

Tags: python, paramiko, nuke

Using The Foundry **Nuke** python version 2.6 can be tricky if you don’t have all the packages like paramiko or urllib2.
My **question** its how can I use for example **paramiko** already installed on my local **python2.6** installation.
Is there a way to **wrap** all my local packages to nukes python?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you just need to append your local Python installation's `site-packages` directory to `sys.path` when Nuke starts up (using an `init.py` file). For example:

```python
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
```

Obviously, the path may be different depending on what platform you are on, and whether or not your standalone interpreter is installed in the default location.

Alternatively, you can append the same path to the PYTHONPATH environment variable in a shell before launching Nuke.

Comment: I know this is old but it's the only hit I get online for this problem. If my system python is 3.x but nuke's is 2.x, do I have to install global python 2.6 and then try what you wrote? Isn't there an easier way like manually download a package and paste it in nuke's folder?